# Does "mouse" in the computer sense come from nautical slang?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, slang

Computer "mouse"   is an English term known and used worldwide. Reference about its origin appears to suggest that the term, which obviously refers to the shape of a small mouse, may actually come from nautical slang.

> - ***The trackball*** (also known as the computer mouse) a related pointing device, was invented in 1941 by [Ralph Benjamin](https://cwtejp1.wikispaces.com/1965+First+Computer+Mouse) as part of a post-World War II-era fire-control radar plotting system called Comprehensive Display System. ***Benjamin was then working for the British Royal Navy Scientific Service.***

(Wikispaces.com)

> - ***[Mouse](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mouse) in the computer sense is from 1965,***  though applied to other things resembling a mouse in shape since 1750, ***mainly nautical.***

(Etymonline)

> - The [earliest](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse) known publication of the term mouse as a computer pointing device is in Bill English's 1965 publication "Computer-Aided Display Control".

(Wikipedia)

One nautical usage I could find refers to a technique called ***[mousing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mousing):***

> - a wrapping of several turns of small stuff around the shank end of a hook.

[image]
The first mouse (1965)

Questions:

- Is there any evidence that may suggest that the "trackball" device invented by Ralph Benjamin was colloquially referred to as "mouse" before the 1965 publication?
- Does the term "mouse" actually come from nautical slang.

Comment: According to wikipedia: *A few months after Telefunken started to sell the Rollkugel, Engelbart released his demo on 9 December 1968. Independently, Douglas Engelbart at the Stanford Research Institute (now SRI International) invented his first mouse prototype in the 1960s with the assistance of his lead engineer Bill English.[13] They christened the device the mouse as early models had a cord attached to the rear part of the device looking like a tail and generally resembling the common mouse.[14]* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse#History

Comment: @MaxWilliams - yes, thats the story we've been told,  my impression is that the colloquial term could have already been in use ...that's what I am asking.

Comment: Possibly. https://books.google.com/books?id=QJkkAQAAMAAJ&q=%22electronic+mouse%22&dq=%22electronic+mouse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm5IfXjOHMAhXFXD4KHapCDf4Q6AEIOTAB

Comment: Not everything has a nautical origin.  The device would have been referred to as a "mouse" by just about anyone who saw it, due to its resemblance to the beast.  There are numerous other uses of "mouse", such as a wad of fluff on the end of a string, sucked through a conduit by an electrician.  The fact that some uses are nautical is not a surprise, as there are all sorts of mouse-looking things in this world.

Comment: And one confusing thing about this whole thread is that a "trackball" is different from a "mouse".  A "trackball" has the ball facing up in a stationary fixture, and the hand is used to directly move the ball.  A "mouse" is an inverted "trackball", where the ball (in the old implementation) is rolled on the desk by moving the fixture.  A "trackball" has similarities to a "joystick".

Comment: @Rathony -  Of the two answers I upvoted only Frank's, but the choice is yours of course.

Answer (score 1):

A man named Douglas Englebart introduced the mouse in 1968, and it's likely that the name derives from its appearance and movement.  People noticed, for example, that the mouse-like shape and size, including a wire that resembles a tail, all pointed to the easy-to--remember name **mouse**.  One can also speculate that the advent of computers created a need among amazed (and threatened) people to bring this incredible piece of technology into the more comfortable human world by giving it a familiar name based on its animal-like attributes.

Comment: Please, reference(s)?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any evidence that may suggest that the "trackball" device invented by Ralph Benjamin was colloquially referred to as "mouse" before the 1965 publication?**

No. The device invented by Ralph Benjamin was not called a mouse. In [an interview in The Telegraph,](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/10174366/Briton-I-invented-the-computer-mouse-20-years-before-the-Americans.html) he says:

> I suggested one way of doing it was with a joystick but the other way
>   of doing it was something you rested your palm on, which we would now
>   call a mouse.

The article says Benjamin's team called the device a *ball tracker.* His use of the phrase "which we would now call a mouse" further suggests the device was not at that time called a mouse.

The same article says the device was kept secret:

> The tracker was described in various internal Admiralty documents, but
>   was kept secret, and not disclosed, explicitly when the technology was
>   patented, in 1946

The fact the original inventor and his team did not call it a mouse, and very few people would have known about it because it was secret, make it extremely unlikely that the device would have been referred to colloquially as a mouse.

**Does the term "mouse" actually come from nautical slang?**

It's unlikely. The inventors themselves say they don't know why they called it a mouse. It was introduced to the public at a demonstration in Stanford Research Institute on December 9, 1968. In that demo, Douglas Engelbart (along with Bill English, widely credited as being the inventor of the mouse) says:

> I don't know why we call it a mouse. It started that way and we never changed it.

You can hear this directly from the horse's mouth, here:

http://web.stanford.edu/dept/SUL/library/extra4/sloan/MouseSite/1968Demo.html

(Clip 12, 00:58)

However, other sources such as [this Wikipedia page,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse) support the common theory that Engelbart and English

> christened the device the mouse as early models had a cord attached to the rear part of the device looking like a tail and generally resembling the common mouse

Perhaps this was the reason, or perhaps someone on the team had nautical knowledge and spotted a resemblance to a [stay mouse.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_mouse) [Occam's razor](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) would suggest the former.